# Regex for two digits in any order

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will match a string as long as it includes 2 or more digits.

What I have:

`/(?=.*\d)(?=.*\d)/`

and

`/\d{2,}/`

The first one will match even if there is one digit, and the second requires that there are 2 consecutive digits. I have tried to combine them in different ways to no avail.

Comment: Can you please precise the language you use when you ask a regex question ?

Answer (score 5):

You can do much simpler :

```
/\d\D*\d/
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I was over complicating the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following expression:

```
.*\d.*\d.*
```

This will match anything that has two digits in it, anywhere. Regardless of where the numbers are. [Example here.](http://regexr.com?36nf1)

You can also do it like this, using ranges:

```
.*[0-9].*[0-9].*
```

[Link.](http://regexr.com?36nf7)

You may also consider using this:

```
\D*\d\D*\d
```

The `\D` will match anything that is not a digit character

Comment: Even better is `\D*\d\D*\d` because the first `.*` can lead to a lot of backtracking. Also, you don't need the last `.*`.

Comment: @Jerry - Even better than that would be to eliminate the first `\D*`; it doesn't really add anything.

Comment: @TedHopp I agree, but there's something else that cannot be certain; it's the language and function OP is using. Case: python with `.match`, `\d\D*\d` will not always work, while `\D*\d\D*\d` will work regardless of function used.

Comment: @Jerry - Well, python also has `.search`, which would do just fine with `\d\D*\d`. (Java also has `.match` and `.find` which behave analogously.) It's just a matter of using the appropriate API; call the wrong function and of course you end up with bad results.

Comment: @TedHopp I know. It's just that OP mightn't know this and tries with `.match` (without mentioning it) and come back saying it's not working, and it just goes into a long exchange (where both OP and answerer might get frustrated at each other).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -E ".*[0-9].*[0-9].*" filename
```

Comment: Nope, read the OP. He doesn't mean two consecutive digits but two digits anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your applications language, but this regex is the most general:

```
^(?=.*\d.*\d)
```

Not all application languages consider *partial* matches as "matching"; this regex will match no matter where in the input the two digits lie.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following depending on the use case:

1. `^(?=(?:\D*\d){2}).*` - The restriction is implemented with a positive lookahead (anchored at the start of string) that requires any two (or more) digits anywhere inside the string (and the regex flavor supports lookaheads) - [**Regex demo #1**](https://regex101.com/r/IrCgMG/1)
2. `^([^0-9]*[0-9]){2}.*` - The regex matches a string that starts with *two* sequences of any non-digit chars followed with a digit char and then contains any text (this pattern is POSIX ERE compliant, to make it POSIX BRE compliant, use `^\([^0-9]*[0-9]\)\{2\}.*`) - [**Regex demo #2**](https://regex101.com/r/IrCgMG/2)
3. `\d\D*\d` - in case you simply want to make sure there is a digit + zero or more chars other than digits followed with a digit and the method you are using allows partial matches - [**Regex demo #3**](https://regex101.com/r/IrCgMG/3).

The first approach is best when you already have a complex pattern and you need to add an extra constraint.

The second one is good for POSIX regex engines.

The third one is best when you implement complex if-else logic for password and other validations with separate error messages per issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this. 
[0-9].{2}

this will help to u